# Ошибка с Math.Ceiling()

Tags: c#

Почему ошибка `Math.Ceiling(275 / 8)`

Comment: `Math.Ceiling(275d / 8d)`. Неоднозначный вызов. `double` и `decimal`. Читайте что пишет студия.

Comment: это я опустил, ошибка "Возвращает наименьшее число, которое больше или равно заданному числу"

Comment: Напишите в коде как я описал выше. Протестите

Comment: Я нашел ошибку, проблема была даже не в этом, в общем я перевожу формулу из экселя а там функция округления работает не по человечески, число 1.2 округлит до 2, но число -0.2 оно округлит не в 0. а в -1 в отличие от Math.Ceiling();  если что-то подобное у c#?

Answer (score 5):

Компилятор на этот код выдает следующее: `The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Math.Ceiling(decimal)' and 'System.Math.Ceiling(double)'`

То есть компилятор не знает, какую именно перегрузку метода Ceiling ему вызвать, ту, что для double или для decimal. В вашем случае методу передаются два инта, которые могут быть неявно приведены как к decimal так и к double, поэтому возникает неопределенность (перегрузки для int нет, поскольку их округлять нет смысла). Чтобы избавиться от ошибки, приведите аргумент к double или к decimal. Например так:

```
Math.Ceiling((double)275/8);
```

Comment: без приведения можно Math.Ceiling(275.0/8);

Answer (score 1):

Потому что поздно округлять, когда ты уже нацело поделил.

```
Math.Ceiling(275. / 8.)
```